# Prawn: is there any way for text justify alignment of all content in bounding_box?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, alignment, bounding-box, prawn

I have an arbitrary text write for user

```
customer_note
```

and I'd like to align the text randomly in a **text align justify**, I have tried to access the text but there is no way to justify the text.

```
if customer_note.present?
  pdf.bounding_box [0, 50], width: 350 do
    pdf.table(customer_note, cell_style: { borders: [] }) do
      cells.padding = 0
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: What do you mean "align the text randomly"? Can you provide some kind of example fo the desired result?